# Visual Studio solution format/syntax reference documentation

Tags: visual-studio, solution

Is there any reference documentation available for the syntax and format of a Visual Studio solution (sln) file?

All I could find is [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx) which is scarce to say the least.